# Method of moments exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

> Find the method of moments estimate for $\lambda$ if a random sample of size $n$ is taken from the exponential pdf,

$$f_Y(y_i;\lambda)= \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \;, \quad y \ge 0$$

$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}y\lambda e^{-y}dy  \\
= \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-\lambda y} dy \\
= -y\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda y}dy \\
=\bigg[\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda}\bigg]\bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty} \\
E[Y] =  \frac{1}{\lambda} \\
$$
Now solve for $\bar{y}$

$$E[Y] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} y_i \\
\bar{y} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \\
\lambda = \frac{1}{\bar{y}} $$

Implies that $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\bar{y}}$

Did I get this one? I have not got the answer for this one in the book.

Comment: Yes your approach is correct

Comment: Thankyou @AhmadBazzi